# How to monitor the I/O of a network-mounted disk in a process specific manner?

Tags: nfs, io

We have a disk mounted via network. `nfsiostat` revealed some basic stats for the whole disk:

```
$ sudo nfsiostat -d /mountpoint

10.20.xxx.xx:/source mounted on /mountpoint:

   op/s     rpc bklog
   7.01
       0.00
lookup:
  ops/s        kB/s       kB/op     retrans     avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
          0.793
      0.214
      0.270
       0 (0.0%)
      0.376
      0.681
readdir:
  ops/s        kB/s       kB/op     retrans     avg RTT (ms)    avg exe (ms)
          0.626
      2.232
      3.567
       0 (0.0%)
      0.324
      0.364

890674 open operations (pathname lookups)
67540669 dentry revalidates and 608885 vfs lookup requests
resulted in 701235 LOOKUPs on the wire
524975 vfs getdents calls resulted in 553108 READDIRs on the wire
```

I'm hoping to find something that would give an `iotop`-style output in a per-process manner. Hope that exists...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `iotop` for that, you gonna have to use the -o option to include network-mounted disks. to install it you can use this command`sudo apt-get install iotop`
Here is an example usage: `sudo iotop -oP -d <network-mount-point>`

Comment: Can I ask which version of iotop this is? in my `0.6` version, neither `-o` or `-d` is related to network-mounted disks.
```
--version             show program's version number and exit
  -o, --only            only show processes or threads actually doing I/O
  -d SEC, --delay=SEC   delay between iterations [1 second]
  -P, --processes       only show processes, not all threads
```